# How does the helper {{templatePath}} work?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <a href="{{postPagePath this}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

this returns an absolute url. postPage is a template I defined. But it automatically gets the helper Path? I don't understand how {{templatePath}} returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Handlebars.js you define helpers in JavaScript in this way:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('helperName', function(argument) {
    // ... you perform actions here
    return whatever; // you return something here
});
```

You then use the helper in this way: `{{helperName something}}`. The `something` there is the argument or arguments that you want to pass to your helper. Those arguments come from the context you are working in. With 'context' we are referring to the JSON data that you pass to Handlebars to fill the template.

Your helper takes that data and builds something with it. It could, for example, concatenate a string with that argument in this way: `var whatever = "<p>" + argument.value1 + "</p>"` and then it returns something as a result, that gets pushed into the page (`return whatever`).

The `Handlebars` that we are using is a global object defined by Handlebars.js for this. It is also used if you want to compile templates: they are included as methods of this global object.

I hope all this is of some help to you.